# SwiftUI公式チュートリアルの動作が正常でない

Tags: swiftui

[Working with UI Controls - SwiftUI Tutorials | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls)

上記ページに書かれているエディットモードの追加の項ですが、正しく動作しないように見えます。
プロジェクトファイルをダウンロードして完成品を実行してみたところ、ユーザネームの変更を行って return（確定）を押す前にDoneを押すとエラーが起きてアプリが落ちてしまいます。

1. これは仕様なのでしょうか
2. どのようにこの問題を回避すれば良いでしょうか

なお、Xcodeのバージョンは11.3.1で、テスト端末のiosは13.3です。

Comment: 「最新版」という表現は時間が経つと意味をなさなくなるので、なるべく具体的な数字を併記した方がより親切になると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何が問題だったのかよく分からないままなのですが、私の環境では何もせずとも解決しました。正常に動作しています。